# What is the most appropriate way to save a Map from Class<?> to an Handler object in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, handler

I have an incoming Queue of Requests and want to be able to register Handler Objects (instance of interface RequestHandler) for different type of Requests (identified by their class). What is the most appropriate (most efficient and fast) way to store this map?

To clearify: I search for the best way to store the relationship between the Class and the Handler.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `Map<Class, RequestHandler>` and made sure the individual types match in the methods which use it.

```
private final Map<Class, RequestHandler> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();

public <T extends Request> void setHandler(Class<T> tClass, RequestHandler<T> handler) {
     handlerMap.put(tClass, handler);
}

public <T extends Request> RequestHandler<T> getHandler(Class<T> tClass) {
     return (RequestHandler<T>) handlerMap.get(tClass);
}
```

Comment: My question was more like which map is the most appropriate map for 'Map<Class<? extends Request, RequestHandler>'

Comment: @th3falc0n If you go down that road, the code gets uglier, but doesn't add any value IMHO.

Comment: You don't understand, that my problem isn't the construction of the Map, but the question which map type is the most efficient and fast way to store the relationship between the class and the handler. Or if there is even a better way than a map.